# Best approach to reuse the same component (with same props) across the pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue-cli 3. Registered globally modal component in main.js:

```
Vue.component('Modal', Modal)
Vue.component('Feedback', Feedback)
```

Then i used these components in every single page:

```
<Modal
  @close="closeModal"
  title="Feedback form"
  :visible="isModalVisible"
  :isActive="isActive"
>
  <template slot="body">
    <Feedback
      :clearValues="clear"
      @close="closeModal"
      @loader="toggleLoader($event)"
    />
  </template>
</Modal>
```

And included mixins with all the required methods. Now i just repeated the same component on every page (with the same props). I feel it's against DRY pattern. Also there's no way to include template in a template (just like in angular). What's the best approach to reuse my modal component on every page?

Comment: Maybe you could look at [Vue Plugins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)?
Might not solve it all, but it will get rid of some of the annoying repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract that composition with the required methods, properties, etc. into a `FeedbackModal` and use that new component instead across pages. Also, with Vue CLI 3, there's no need to register components globally if you use ES `import/export` statements.

Comment: Then my emits would stop work. And anyway, i would have to inject `FeedbackModal` in every page again.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you mean, but possibly related to this issue and workaround: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332#issuecomment-263444492